# Why descendant-or-self:: is not allowed in template pattern?

Tags: xslt

Suppose I have the following XML (which is the embedding of [TEI](http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/ref-bibl.html) annotation scheme into HTML):

`<p>(See, for example, <bibl type="journal" xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><author>Greger IH, et al.</author> <date>2007</date>, <title>Trends Neurosci.</title> <biblScope type="vol">30</biblScope> (<biblScope type="issue">8</biblScope>): <biblScope type="pp">407-16</biblScope></bibl>).</p>`

Now I want to copy all annotation nodes *as is* into resulting XHTML but only rename `<title>` to `<bibTitle>` (as `<title>` is only allowed in `<head>`), so I used the following transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:bibl/descendant-or-self::*">
    <xsl:variable name="nodeName">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'title'">bibTitle</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Changing of the namespace occurs here, but we don't care -->
    <xsl:element name="{$nodeName}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()|tei:bibl//text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

However it does not compile and breaks with following error:

`Only child:: and attribute:: axes are allowed in match patterns!  Offending axes = descendant-or-self`

When I change the match rule to `<xsl:template match="tei:bibl|tei:bibl//*">` it starts working as intended. But that should be identical to `descendant-or-self::*`, right? Have I hit the transformer implementation limitation here?

First I've tested with Mozilla 3.5 internal transformer, then with Xalan 2.7.1 – same negative result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This limitation is valid *only* for any *location step* within the template's match pattern**. It is by design (mandated by the W3C **[XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns)** and **[XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#pattern-syntax)** specifications) -- to ensure efficient XSLT processing.

**Do note**: One can freely use any axis (including `descending-or-self::`) withinin the predicates that follow any location step.

**Update**:

Here is a short, complete example of using the `descendant-or-self::` axis in the `match` attribute of `xsl:template`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[descendant-or-self::num > 5]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
 <num>1</num>
 <num>2</num>
 <num>3</num>
 <num>4</num>
 <num>5</num>
 <num>6</num>
 <num>7</num>
 <num>8</num>
 <num>9</num>
 <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result: any `num` elements with value >= 5 are deleted:**

```
<nums>
  <num>1</num>
  <num>2</num>
  <num>3</num>
  <num>4</num>
  <num>5</num>
</nums>
```

Comment: Can you give your idea, how exactly this limitation influences the  performance (by re-writing the rule to equivalent the transformer has to perform the same job anyway)? And can you please provide the example of what is *predicate that follow any location step* (for me to know what is the correct usage of this axe)? Thanks.

Comment: @dma_k: If you provide a specific transformation problem (an XML document, the desired result, rules) then I will be glad to show you how the templates could be specified using allowed syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hard requirement by [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns):

> Although patterns must not use the descendant-or-self axis, patterns may use the // operator as well as the / operator.

Comment: Have you got the idea, what is the reason of this limitation? (one can write the equivalent rule anyway)

Comment: Questions about "why" specs say what they do are very hard to answer. An accurate answer depends on careful historical research in the minutes of the WG meetings: was the facility ever proposed, if so, what was the result of the voting, and did the people voting record their reasons for voting the way they did? Rather than doing this research, it's tempting to offer a post-hoc rationale: "this is why the decision seems to make sense". In this case, I think the only post-hoc rationale is that the WG was trying to keep patterns as simple as possible in the interests of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can rewrite the pattern into an equivalent one that doesn't repeat mention of `tei:bibl`:

```
<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::tei:bibl]">
```

As to why the limitation is there, the general answer, yes, is for performance. Perhaps the limitations are overly conservative, because, as you pointed out, the rewrite of descendant-or-self in this case is trivial.

I regularly get annoyed by this limitation (that you can use // but not descendant).

Comment: Thank you for nice example of how `ancestor-or-self::` can be forced in the predicate. I think this makes XSLT engine to puff even more :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a case where it is not enough:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <c>
        <c/>
      </c>
    </c>
  </b>
  <c>
    <c>
      <c/>
    </c>
  </c>
</a>
```

now I want to match only:

```
*[self::a or self::b][p(.)]/c/descendent-or-self::c
```

i.e., if the predicate p(.) is true on a, I want a/c, a/c/c, a/c/c/c and if it is true on b, I want b/c, b/c/c, and b/c/c/c.

But I do not want a/b/c, a/b/c/c, etc. just because the predicate matches on a and not on b.

If I make a match pattern:

```
*[self::a or self::b][p(.)]//c
```

then I match all of them which I do not want.

So I have to do it backwards in the bracket:

```
c[ancestor-or-self::c/parent::*[self::a or self::b][p(.)]]
```

I think I just convinced myself that this restriction isn't really a logical restriction, however, I think the excuse not to allow proper axis steps in match patterns is pretty lame, because when I need this, I need this, who cares if it is not as fast as if I use simpler expressions.