# XSLT template match: recipe for moving disallowed axes to predicate

Tags: xslt, xpath, match, axes

I understand that the XSLT 1.0 standard disallows most XPath axes in the [StepPatern](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#NT-StepPattern) portion of a match expression. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081773/why-descendant-or-self-is-not-allowed-in-template-pattern) where the recommended alternative was using the desired axis in a [Predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates).)

I have a complex XPath expression that returns a node set, *`node-set-expression`*. I would like to make a template matching *`node-set-expression`*`/ following-sibling::*`. Is there a general way to rewrite this to use Predicates so that it can be used in the `match` attribute of a XSLT `template` element?

And equivalently, is there a general way to translate the following:

*`node-set-expression`*`/ preceding-sibling::*`

*`node-set-expression`*`/ self-and-following-sibling::*` (this is shorthand; I know it's [not a valid axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584045/xpath-select-self-and-following-sibling-together))

If Predicates won't work, are there any other general approaches?

Comment: Can you include a sample XML file, a template for the node you are matching from and which node you want to target?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 I tend to handle such cases by preselecting the matching nodes in a global variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="special-nodes" select="//something/preceding-sibling::*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[. intersect $special-nodes]"/>
```

In XSLT 3.0 this will simplify further to

```
<xsl:template match="$special-nodes"/>
```

An advantage of doing it this way is that searching for the "special nodes" once is likely to be a lot more efficient than testing every node against every such pattern when doing an apply-templates; it also makes the condition clearer, in my view.

The only general solution I know to your question for XSLT 1.0 is to write the pattern as

```
<xsl:template match="*[count(.|//something/preceding-sibling::*) =
                       count(//something/preceding-sibling::*)]">
```

but that really is too horribly inefficient to contemplate.